# Оптимизация кода для больших чисел на входе (до 10^12 включительно)

Tags: c++, математика, оптимизация, олимпиада

Очень простая задача: дано целое число n, нужно вывести все его делители в порядке возрастания, (1 ≤ n ≤ 10^12). Задача с codeforces, не проходит по времени начиная с 9 теста. Вот мой код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include<cmath>
#include <string>
#include<cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include<queue>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    unsigned long long n;
    cin >> n;
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <=n; ++i){
        if (n % i == 0){
            cout << i << ' ';
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ссылка на задачу? Там разбора нет ее?

Comment: Как минимум идти только до корня квадратного из числа. Но тогда конечно придется сохранять второй делитель и выводить его позже (что бы сохранить порядок вывода). т.е. скажем ищем делители из 1000,  значит идем до 33, но когда нашли делитель 2, то сразу запоминаем (1000/2) делитель 500, его надо будет последним выводить

Comment: ссылка на задачу https://codeforces.com/group/JD1DlOu2l1/contest/360496/problem/C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `i` — делитель `n`, то `n/i` тоже делитель `n`...

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    set<unsigned long long> v;
    unsigned long long n;
    cin >> n;
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i*i <= n; ++i)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            v.insert(i);
            v.insert(n/i);
        }
    }

    for(auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) cout << *i << " ";
}
```

Comment: помогло, понял, спасибо!